# ImportError: No module named pip after trying to upgrade pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using a MacOS 10.15 and Python version 3.7.7

I wanted to upgrade pip so I ran `pip install --upgrade pip`, but it turns out my pip was gone (it shows `ImportError: No module named pip` when I want to use `pip install ...`)

I tried several methods like `python3 -m ensurepip`, but it returns

```
Looking in links: /var/folders/sc/f0txnv0j71l2mvss7psclh_h0000gn/T/tmpchwk90o3

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (49.6.0.post20200814)

Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.2.2)
```

and `pip install` still does not work and returns the same error message.

I also tried `easy_install pip` and other methods but pip still does not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

---

Update:
Using the method from @cshelly, it works on my computer!

Comment: try using pip3 install (module) instead of pip install (module)

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` work?

Comment: Try using 
``` pip3 --version ```
, see if it gives any output or throws error
If it throws error probably pip is not installed

Comment: @TheHappyBee it still returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'":(

Comment: @fsimonjetz it returns "/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python3: No module named pip"

Comment: @cshelly I update the output in my original post since the number of characters is limited here.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```sh
python3 -m pip --upgrade pip
```

The `-m` flag will run a library module as a script.

Comment: Although it is more typing, I am finding that this is a more reliable way of doing it.

Comment: @TimRoberts, `-U` can be used instead of `--upgrade` to save some typing, but I wanted to be more explicit to provide this answer.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf The output is still "/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python3: No module named pip"...do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Doi_Ann, what is the output of `which python3`?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf it returns "/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python3"

Comment: @Doi_Ann, can you run `conda install -c anaconda pip`

Comment: This fails for me, giving: "/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed"

Answer (score 1):

Since it says no module named pip, thus pip is not installed in your system
So you may try

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

to download pip directly then you can use execute it using -

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

For details you may refer - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/

PS: You may need to use **sudo** to make use of administrative privileges.

Comment: When I tried to run the second command, it returns " Found existing installation: setuptools 49.6.0.post20200814
Uninstalling setuptools-49.6.0.post20200814:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '__init__.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions." What should I add/modify? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you are using mac run this commands in sudo mode, 
just use sudo before the command @Doi_Ann

Comment: That works!!! Finally!! Thank a lot, I really appreciate!! @cshelly

Comment: What if your machine is not connected to the internet?